# getmdl.io input underline issue with material form

Tags: material-design, material-design-lite

I am using getmdl.io Material forms. The form was working fine. But some browsers are now not showing the underline.

[image]

Was working fine until yesterday.  The issue is only on some chrome browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was able to find a solution to it. Basically it seems the new chrome version

Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) is sometimes not recognising the border value in REM. So 0.0625 rem is not recognized.

[image]

When I changed it to 1 px. It sharted showing.

[image]

Hope this help others.

Vipin